# Can I abuse a predicate to perform operations on the elements before remove_if removes them?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++03

I have a std::list of objects. The list is sorted and must stay that way. I need to find those objects that satisfy a certain criterion (I have a predicate for this), pass them to a function, and then delete the objects from the list.

It's not too hard to write a loop that calls `std::find_if()`, invokes the operation on its result (if any), calls `list.erase()`, and passes the result of that as begin iterator to the next call to `std::find_if()`. IME, however, people find such code harder to read than it is to write it.

So I would preferably employ some algorithm(s) from the std lib rather than writing my own loop.

One idea was to (ab)use `std::list<>::remove_if()`: Invoke the operation on the elements that match _from the *predicate*, before it returns `true`, so that the list will delete the elements. Would that be standard-conforming? (The items themselves won't be changed, only data they refer to.)

Or can you come up with a better solution? (Again, the main objective is to make this easy to read and understand.) Maybe it's because I just ran into it, but to me it seems this might not be an uncommon usage pattern for a sequence of objects.

*Note:* For the time being , we're firmly stuck in C++03 land. `:-/` C++11/14/17 solutions would be interesting and thus welcome, but I do need something that works with C++03.

Comment: You can use `for_each`, store iterators somewhere during execution and remove those elements at the end?

Comment: @skypjack: I had thought of this, too. It seems clumsy and cumbersome, though, and requires two passes over the list. (Note that the list is protected by a mutex, which blocks other operations while this is in progress.)

Comment: One pass over the list, one pass over the iterators (likely a few ones). Anyway, I see what you mean, but I find a bit tricky the idea of performing actions in an unary predicate ideally aimed only to check a condition.

Comment: @skypjack: You forget the pass over the list to erase the objects found. Or am I missing something? And, yes, I find this tricky, too. That's why I came here.

Comment: If you have the iterators, you don't have to pass over the list to erase them. It has constant complexity. Moreover, erasing an iterator doesn't invalidate other iterators. We are speaking of a `std::list`, right?

Comment: Otherwise you could move elements to be erased from a list to another one, release the lock, do your job and swap that one with an empty list at the end.

Comment: @skypjack: Ah, mea culpa. Where you wrote "remove those elements at the end" I read "invoke `remove_if()` – which you clearly didn't write. However, I just ran into `std::stable_partition()`, which looks exactly like what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I abuse a predicate to perform operations on the elements before `remove_if` removes them?

Yes. There's nothing in the standard specification that requires the predicate to be a pure function. So this C++11 solution would be perfectly fine:

```
my_list.remove_if([f, pred](Elem const& e){
    if (pred(e)) {
        f(e);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Nothing even requires the predicate to ever return `true`. You can even use `remove_if` as a poor man's, unnecessarily confusing `for_each`:

```
my_list.remove_if([f](Elem const& e){
    f(e);
    return false;
});
```

That's pointless and inefficient, but it's definitely standards conforming.

You can write the equivalent in C++03 as a function object. Whether or not you find that easier to read than the for loop is a matter of opinion. But it's not wrong.

Comment: I hardly find an abuse of intended API and general expectations "not wrong". Otherwise code ends up with lots of little gems. It might not be violation of a specification; leave it at that.

Comment: In the end, I went with `std::stable_partition`, which nicely puts the items I am looking for at either end of the list, where I can process and delete them. Still, this does answer my original question, so it gets the tick from me.